# Conditional Probability equal to zero

Tags: self-study, conditional-probability

Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be two independent Normal variables with mean $\theta$ and variance $1$. Let $S=X_1+X_2$ and consider the following conditional probability:

$$P \left[ X_1 \leq x_1; X_2 \leq x_2 |S=s \right]$$

If we assume that $x_1 \leq x_2$ and $x_2 \leq s$, then why does this conditional probability equal zero? I have been struggling to notice the impossibility here.

Thanks.

Comment: How did you determine this conditional probability must be zero? Is there perhaps an unstated assumption about the sign of $s$?

Comment: @whuber I didn't, my book says that this "clearly" equals zero. Is it true? I do not see any such assumption either.

Comment: Book and page could help.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos Introduction to the Theory of Statistics, third edition by Mood, Graybill, Boes, page 304. It is an intermediate text, most commonly referred to as MGB. The point is to show that the conditional probability does not depend on $\theta$ and thus $S$ is sufficient.  It being $0$ accomplishes that.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos I just found it in pdf form, here http://www.colorado.edu/economics/morey/7818/MoodGraybillBoesBook/MGB3rdSearchable.pdf . Feel free to take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a possible mistake. 
The book states that this probability is "clearly zero" when the following inequality holds ("case [iii]")

$$[iii] \qquad x_1\le x_2 < s$$

We have that (skipping the limit notation to handle $S=s$)

$$P \left[ X_1 \leq x_1; X_2 \leq x_2 |S=s \right] = P \left[ S-X_2 \leq x_1; X_2 \leq x_2 |S=s \right]$$

$$=P \left[ s-x_1\le X_2 \leq x_2\right]$$

For this probability to equal $0$ it must be the case that either the interval is a single point or that it is an impossible interval, i.e, we must have

$$s-x_1 \ge x_2 \Rightarrow s\ge x_1+x_2$$

which does not necessarily follow from the assumed inequality in the beginning.

Comment: Thank you for confirming my suspicions. That passage is very badly written I reckon.

Comment: Hi Alecos. I wanted to ask you: in the derivation of probabilities, why didn't you use the usual conditional distribution ratio? Your way is better and faster and I would appreciate the intuition there. Thank you.

Comment: Because $P(S=s)$ would surface, and then I could not avoid using the "limit notation" in order to handle the fact that $P(S=s)=0$. Also, why bring into the picture a more complicated joint event?

Comment: So you take $P(S=s)=1$?

Comment: In a sense, yes, since I insert the conditioning event directly into the conditioned event and make the probability unconditional